# Pre-made Javascript testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, tdd

I've been messing around with libraries like Jasmine, and it seems strange to me that I have to write the explicit inputs to my functions when making assertions. It's difficult for me to think about all the obscure things that could be passed in through a form, and I have this feeling like I'm only testing for the things I was thinking about when I wrote the function to start.

Are there any tools that automatically check obscure inputs for you? Or how should I be sure to think outside the box and test the things that I normally wouldn't think of? Is my question off base?

Comment: Are you reffering to validating input to ensure no code is injected?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about characters that should not be in data that comes from a user? Are you trying to prevent code or sql injection?